# node.js connect-auth app? example (user registration / user / session management)

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, session, node.js-connect

I'm trying to get the hang of node.js and am looking for an authentication example. Hopefully with connect-auth and using http digest with hash and salt.

I watched this but it doesn't seem very secure:

http://nodetuts.com/tutorials/13-authentication-in-express-sessions-and-route-middleware.html#video

Does anyone have a better example?
Mongodb preferred!

User Management and authentication is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since i was mentioned by @jpstrikesback, i'll post an answer here :)

I recently built 2 applications on top of the whole Express/Connect stack ([node-blog](https://github.com/schaermu/node-blog) and [node-chat](https://github.com/schaermu/node-chat)). node-chat is the more recent project, i just updated it to work with the most recent Express 2 Beta (express@2.0.0beta2) and Connect 1.0 (connect@1.0.3). node-blog may follow later this day ;)

node-chat also contains some socket.io awesomeness and is the more tidy project in general. If you have any questions concerning one of those projects, just get at me at SO.

**NOTE**: since connect-mongodb is broken for the latest release of Connect, i'm using the in-memory session storage for now (until the connect-mongodb middleware is fixed).

**Update**: there is a new session storage middleware for connect, seems to be working : [connect-mongo](https://github.com/kcbanner/connect-mongo)

Comment: sadly you posted too late for the bounty, but thank you very much. I hope to see your apps updated soon

Comment: updated node-chat, be sure to have the latest express/connect/connect-mongo and jade installed (through npm).

Comment: thanks again. :) node-blog should probably also get an update as well, eg bodyParser. Also connect-mongodb seems to be fixed.

Comment: connect-mongodb is not broken anymore :)

Answer (score 4):

Express authentication using Redis for session store and Couchdb for database (in coffeescript!)

https://gist.github.com/652819

You need to fetch the modules from NPM or via git.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, this is cheeky cause Schaermu should get the points :) but this should be helpful:

https://github.com/schaermu/node-blog

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Sadly because of how fast node.js is changing, this doesn't work with the latest versions of connect!

Comment: yeah, you'll probably need express 1.0.7 & connect 0.5.10 for that example